# How to set the program title in python

Tags: python, macos, title, menubar

I have been building a large python program for a while, and would like to know how I would go about setting the title of the program? On a mac the title of program, which has focus, is shown in the top left corner of the screen, next the apple menu. Currently this only shows the word "Python", but I would of course like to my program's title there instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It depends on what type of application you have. If it's a graphical application, most graphical toolkits allow you to change the title of a window (tk, which comes with python, allows you to do this by calling the `title()` method of your window object, as does gtk, for which you can use the `set_title()` method on a `Gtk.Window` object)

If you're talking about changing the title of the terminal window (for mac or Linux), the you have this option (from [here](http://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=85567)):

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("\x1b]2;Another Title\x07")
```

For Windows, there's a different method:

```
import os
os.system("title Yet Another Title")
```

Comment: Thanks for the Windows answer as an aside. Was very useful to me.

Comment: sys.stdout.write("\x1b]2;Another Title\x07") changes the current window title, what if i need to change the title of a terminal opened by python subprocess in linux

Comment: I'm looking for that answer as well.  For me I'm calling terminal to open new windows and I want those new windows named.  I'm trying to use cmd = echo -n -e "\033]0;xxx\007;python3 myFile.py

Answer (score 3):

Since your program is interpreted by Python, then what actually is run is Python itself - the **interpreter** program. You would have to have your Python script merged with Python into a single executable and that would be able to have a separate name. For windows there is py2exe, that does that, but I have no idea if there is a similar tool for Mac OS (and if there is any need for that, there is some BSD under the hood right?).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info, there is in fact an equivalent called "py2app", but I wasn't expecting that that was the only way to do it